# Selenium python метод move_to_element пролистывает элемент

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Пишу парсер. На странице есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую происходит догрузка товара. Так как нажатие можно производить только по видимому элементу, использую метод move_to_element для скроллинга к элементу. Все работает хорошо. Но начиная с 37 загрузки товара, элемент как бы "пролистывается" и находится теперь в верхней части, скрываясь под верхним поиском и не давая нажать по нему. Почему это происходит и как исправить?
Нормальный скроллинг к элементу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблемный скроллинг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p=40&i=1

Код:

```
while(True):
    catalog_items_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".catalog-items-more:not(.hidden)")))

    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(catalog_items_more).perform();
    catalog_items_more.click()
```

Либо как нажимать на элемент без скроллинга?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    self.selenium.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") # на экран вниз
    time.sleep(1)
    self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//*[name()="path"][@class="active"]').click()  # выбор мест
except NoSuchElementException:
    time.sleep(1)
    self.selenium.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, -250);") # идем вверх
```

Суть в следующем, если ты не видишь элемент,то листаешь его. Можешь листать не на всю высоту документа document.body.scrollHeight

Прокрутку до элемента попробуйте так:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
element = driver.find_element_by_id("my-id")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Или еще так:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```